# GAE OAuth Java: No authentication header information

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth

I have this error:

```
WARNING: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
Exception : No authentication header information
```

I am using GWT with eclipse.
I really don't know what's wrong in my code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Client side EntryPoint class:**

```
private static final String GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
private static final String GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
private static final String CONTACTS_SCOPE = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";
private static final Auth AUTH = Auth.get();

public void onModuleLoad() {
        final AuthRequest req = new AuthRequest(GOOGLE_AUTH_URL, GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID).withScopes(CONTACTS_SCOPE);

    AUTH.login(req, new Callback<String, Throwable>() {
        public void onSuccess(String token) {               
            ABASession.setToken(token);
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("Error:\n" + caught.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I store the token in a class that I will use later.

**Server side: ContactServiceImpl (RPC GAE procedure)**

//The token stored previously is then passed through RPC
    public List printAllContacts(String token) {
        try {
            GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();

```
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey("My consumer key");
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret("My consumer secret");

        PrivateKey privKey = getPrivateKey("certificate/akyosPrivateKey.key");

        OAuthRsaSha1Signer signer = new OAuthRsaSha1Signer(privKey);

        ContactsService service = new ContactsService("XXX");
        service.setProtocolVersion(ContactsService.Versions.V3);
        oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(token);
        service.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);

        // Request the feed
        URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?xoauth_requestor_id=xxx.yyy@gmail.com");

        ContactFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
        for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
            for (Email email : entry.getEmailAddresses()) {
                contactNames.add(email.getAddress());
            }
        }
        return contactNames;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set the scope

```
oauthParameters.setScope("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
```